# Bootloader issue - How do I completely remove Linux from my system? fully detailed description

Tags: multi-boot, grub, efi, bootmgr

The *goal* was to successfully **install Windows 10 upgrade.**

System configuration :
Dell Inspiron 3537,
 i5 4th gen processor,
 6GB RAM,
 1TB HDD,
 2GB AMD Graphics.

Before install :
I have a **Dual-boot system** with Ubuntu GNOME alongside my genuine Windows 8.1.

I assumed there would be a problem with the bootmanager so I decided to **remove the Linux from my system**. Followed the instructions given in the how-to-geek website tutorial(linked at the end).

Accordingly,I **deleted 2 partitions** 65GB and 2GB(I guess swap partion). Screenshot added to the gdrive folder

Next,I booted into Windows Repair from Disc
and entered in cmd:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

After removal the **problem** began,(gdrive link with screenshots given at the end)

The **first boot screen**:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2

    Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported. For the first word,TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
    grub>exit
    Boot succeeded-info
```

The **second boot screen**:

```
Boot Manager (windows)
```

The **third boot screen**:

```
Windows 8.1/10 boot up (Dell logo)
```

Then the system finally starts Windows.

I **installed Windows 10 upgrade**,still the **same problem**.

**Please guide me** through removing Linux entirely (removing grub) from the system.
I want to clean-install Windows 10 of which I know the process how-to-do-it.

Do I remove the EFI partition too?

Do I just directly perform a clean install?

Please help. Thanks a lot!

> Links:
>
> Gdrive screenshots: https://goo.gl/hUZIKG
>
> How-to-geek tutorial: http://goo.gl/Wqk4pe

Comment: Why not install W10 and format all partitions before picking your un-allocated space?

Comment: I do not have enough portable storage for backup,hence in a clean install I will only format the OS partition.

Comment: In the repair try bootrec /fixboot then you try the one with fixmbr which you mentioned above.

Comment: I have tried that. Did not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you wrote:

> I do not have enough portable storage for backup

***FIX THIS PROBLEM IMMEDIATELY!!!!!***

I *frequently* see problems on this and other sites caused by people who have inadequate backups. Because of accidents or hardware failures, they lose all their personal data.

That out of the way, your computer uses EFI firmware, not BIOS. One of your repair attempts used `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`, but that works only on BIOS-based computers. Under EFI, the boot process involves:

1. An entry in NVRAM tells the computer what boot loader (stored on the [EFI System Partition, or ESP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)) to launch. In fact, a list of boot options is stored; each one is tried in turn until one succeeds.
2. Control passes to the boot loader specified by the NVRAM. This boot loader may do any number of things, but ultimately....
3. The boot loader loads an OS kernel.

Your problem is caused by the fact that GRUB 2 (the usual Linux boot loader) is often configured to rely on files stored on the Linux filesystem. Thus, when you deleted the Linux partition, the EFI continued to launch GRUB 2 (which was stored on the ESP), but GRUB 2 was unable to read its configuration file, and you got the emergency `grub>` prompt. This is a design flaw in GRUB 2, or at least in the way it's often configured -- it really should *not* be depending upon configuration files stored anywhere but on the ESP.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. **Delete GRUB** -- If you delete the GRUB files from the ESP, the firmware will move on to the next item in the boot list. To do this, you must mount the ESP in an OS (or launch an EFI shell) and delete the files, which are normally stored in a directory like `EFI/ubuntu` or `EFI/fedora` (depending on the distribution you installed). The ESP is easy to spot with most partitioning tools, since it's a FAT partition early on the disk. Sometimes it's marked as an "EFI System Partition" or something similar. Your first screen shot shows it, in fact -- it's your second partition. In Windows, you can mount it with the `/S` option to `mountvol`, as in `mountvol /S E:` to mount it as `E:`. In Linux, it mounts like any other partition, with the `mount` command.
2. **Re-organize your boot order** -- This can be done with `efibootmgr` in Linux or `bcdedit` in Windows; however, in Windows the [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) utility presents an easier and more flexible GUI way to control the boot order. Whatever tool you use, delete GRUB 2 from the boot order, or at least move it below the Windows boot loader in priority. To use `efibootmgr`, first type it alone to see what boot options exist; then use `-b` and `-B` to delete one, as in `efibootmgr -b 5 -B` to delete the `Boot0005` entry; or use `-o` to rearrange the boot order, as in `efibootmgr -o 2,5,3` to have the system try `Boot0002` first, then `Boot0005`, then `Boot0003`.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks! It worked.
Can I proceed to Windows 10 clean install now?